# How do I generate sentences with Rita.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, markov-chains, markov

**I installed Rita through Node, following a RiTa.js egghead.io tutorial. After running the following code in my rita.js file on terminal, it shows a lot of data and says**

> Error: No valid sentence-starts remaining

```
var rita= require('rita');

var inputText= 'The blue bus drove by a crowded street. All the children were singing. It was a great bus ride.';

var markov= new rita.markov(5)

markov.addText(inputText)

var sentences= markov.generate(2);

console.log(sentences)
```

Comment: The code in [the official documentation](https://rednoise.org/rita/reference/RiTa/markov/index.html) produces that result too.

Comment: You may want to [log an issue](https://github.com/dhowe/ritajs/issues).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify the markov input to '2' (limit) and it'll work.
Here's the example running:
https://notebook.xbdev.net/index.php?page=ritalanguage2&

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33144360)